# Speed up JSON Serialization from C# to JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization, asmx

I want to **serialize my set of data to JSON**.

Here is the snippet code of my ASMX to serialize the object

```
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetProviderMemberDetail(string jsonString)
        {
            BPMember bp = new BPMember();
            List<BOProvider> listProvider = bp.GetProviderMemberDetail(jsonString);
            return ConvertToSerializedJson(listProvider);
        }
```

Here is what the ConvertToSerializedJson does

```
     public string ConvertToSerializedJson(Object listBO)
        {
            string jsonReturn = String.Empty;
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            jsonReturn = serializer.Serialize(listBO);
            return jsonReturn;
        }
```

The amount of data that I have to serialize is much, approximately 200.000 datas.

I have tried this method, my browser got hang and got not responding, I have to wait 6 minutes to complete.

Second attempt, I tried serializer function from **Newtonsoft.Json**,
added

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

and changing the serializer code with

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listProvider);
```

It speed up a bit, but makes my browser almost hang too. It takes 4minutes to complete all the serialization.

The question is, how I can speed up the serialization thing? My query only takes 4seconds to finish the query execution and retrieving the data from DB. The one that take it long is the serialization process
Is there any function that will run faster than this? Please post the names library or function and the benchmark, I will update this post if I get good significant changes.

Cheers.

**UPDATED**
This is why I love you guys, I have speed up, with advice from you kind-guys, and here is the things that I "tweak" a little.

As @Saravanan said, I have reduced any unused (or with little frequency used) on my BO. That was a successful tweak. from 300sec (5mins) to 18sec.

As @sanguaire stated, I am trying to use fastJSON library ([download here](http://fastjson.codeplex.com/releases/view/610798)), compile to dll, add reference to my project and this speed a bit.

The times required to retrieve 200.000 datas for me is approximately 14 sec to 18 sec. This is my benchmark with 17columns.

[image]

Thank you for the opinion guys. Sorry for the late reply. I will (if my points reach the up vote standard) vote up both of your answer here.

Comment: how big is your bo object and is it nested?

Comment: You can find a good article on codeproject about different libraries for JSON serialization (with benchmarks). You can find it here [Article about JSON libraries](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON) Bye.

Comment: @Saravanan It has 50 attributes, only `code { get; set; } ` for all the members. It has 50 attributes, but in my case, I only use 10 attributes to them. Did the attributes count has effect? Is so I will make new BO with less member because current BO member object is for my team use

Comment: definitely it will have impact...also, i believe attribute are simple type...in that case it will help

Comment: Ya, all attributes are simple type such as string and int only.
so what is your suggestion @Saravanan?

Comment: create a object with 10 attributes and check.. it should speed up..